# mod_rewrite not passing GET values

Tags: php, apache

the php page is not receiving the GET variable and is producing an undefined index error for textSearch.
I've turned off multiviews, and added QSA as suggested in related posts.

my .htaccess looks like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The `$_GET` variable should be named textSearch

```
<form action='users/index.php' method"GET">
   <input type='text' name='textSearch'>
   <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

[EDIT]
As mentioned in the comments, the form's location is in `localhost/Build_3/index.php`, and is passing the 'textSearch' variable to `localhost/Build_3/users/index.php`

**[EDIT]**

Directory structure is as follows:
default home page is `Build_3/index.php`
user home page is `Build_3/users/index.php`

The form in `Build_3/index.php` is supposed to go to `Build_3/users/index.php` and provide the variable textSearch.
I have one `.htaccess` in `Build_3`, and one in the `Build_3/users` directory.

Comment: `_$GET` what?.... Its `$_GET['textSearch']`

Comment: [edited] _$GET['textSearch']

Comment: @WhiteBit Add `%{QUERY_STRING}` at the end of the rule. Check out my answer for another point too!

Comment: What URL gets produced by the form?

Comment: http://localhost/subdirectory/users/searchstring is the URL

Comment: i'm trying to pass the variable from localhost/subdirectory/index.php to localhost/subdirectory/users/index.php since i'm trying to create a user page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add `%{QUERY_STRING}` at the end of the rule.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.dummy$ ./?page=dummy&%{QUERY_STRING} 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

#### Notes:

1. What's that `Options -MultiViews` doing above?
2. In order for `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]` to work, you need to add some dummy conditions, like I have added above.

---

#### Update #1

As far as I understood you, correct me if my understanding is wrong:

1. There is a form in the `Build_3/index.php`, which has a `post` method, taking to `Build_3/users/index.php`. So I assume that you have the following with you:

   ```
   <form method="post" action="users/index.php">
   ...
   ...
   </form>
   ```
2. You have two `.htaccess` files. Why is there one in the `users` directory? Okay, I am not sure, why you have one in the `Build_3/` then. If you want the users access the URL as:

   ```
   http://Build_3/users/5
   ```

   And it should get redirected this way:

   ```
   http://Build_3/users/index.php?id=5
   ```

   Then you need to change your `.htaccess` file in the `Build_3/users/` directory this way:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule (.*)\.dummy$ ./?page=dummy&%{QUERY_STRING} 
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
   ```

Comment: hey Praveen, I'm unfamiliar the dummy conditions that you mention. I believed RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L] would have suffice. I am also trying to figure out what multiviews does, but it was a popular answer for similar posts. The fix is still not working though.

Comment: Do one thing. Just copy the code which I pasted and remove the first line. Save the file and try. Lemme know the results. `:)`

Comment: Thanks praveen. I pasted this into .htaccess but i'm still not able to get it to work.

my directory structure is as follows:
my main directory is named Build_3, and the index.php has a form, which on submit, has form action='Build_3/users/index.php'
it only has one variable (textSearch) and so i'm expecting it to be passed as Build_3/users/index.php?textSearch='somevalue'.
I have 2 .htaccess files. one in Build_3, and one in user. the one i changed was the one in the user directory.

Comment: @WhiteBit Can you update this in the question. Unable to get the full sense of it. :|

Comment: Bam. Thanks a lot. It was actually working all this time, except I had a bunch of code at the bottom that was completely messing up everything else. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Woah!!! Awesome that it worked! :)